# Intersection query with Lucene

Tags: lucene, intersection

With Zned Lucene, when i search for `field1:value1`, I have 1000 hits returned.
When I search for `field2:value2`, I have 0 hits returned.
And when i search for `field1:value1 AND field2:value2`, I have 1000 hits returned, but I'd rather like to have 0 hits returned !

Why doesn't it do the intersection of the query ?

Comment: Please post your solution as new answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find myself the solution. Actually it works fine this way using the zend lucene API :

```php
$query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_MultiTerm();
$query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term(value1, field1), true);
$query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term(value2, field2), true);
$hits  = $index->find($query);
```